# How to combine two different conditional tags on Wordpress Plugin Widget-Logic?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How can I combine two different conditional tags on Wordpress Plugin Widget-Logic? How to combine page and single-post in one conditional tag or in one widget?

For example I tried:

```
!is_page(9) ) || !is_single(10)
```

But it does not work. Does anybody know a solution?

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code you posted cannot work because it has unbalanced parentheses.

```
!is_page(9) || !is_single(10)
```

is what you mean. However, I doubt that it is what you *want*, because it is enough that one of the two predicates is true for the whole `OR` expression to be true, and the two predicates will never be simultaneously false (you will never be on page 9 and post 10 at the same time!): your expression will always evaluate true.

I suspect that what you want is that your widget appears on all pages except page 9 and on all posts except post 10. This would be coded as

```
!is_page(9) && !is_single(10)
```

or (if this is easier to understand)

```
!(is_page(9) || is_single(10))
```

Both will work.

Answer (score 0):

thanks.

And how would be the correct syntax here?

!is_page( array( 1,2,3,4,5) || !is_single( array( 6,7,8,9,10) )

I get a parse error

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

O.k. it works like this

!is_page( array( 1,2,3,4,5) ) && !is_single( array( 6,7,8,9,10) )